# What do the colours mean in Terminal when running Django server?

Tags: django, terminal

I'm trying to debug jQuery in an application I am developing in Django and I am just wondering where I can get information on the colors output by terminal when I am running the Django server? This is running on a local machine

Ive tried googeling but I only seem to get information on how I can change the color of the default terminal output for day to day processes.

[image]

Comment: They appear to correspond to the HTTP response status code.

Answer (score 2):

It's more relevant to look at the [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_status_codes) than the colours, but a quick look seems to suggest

- Default: 200; all OK
- Yellow: 404 Not found (plus I imagine 403 and 401)
- Green: 301 or 302; redirects
- Pink: 500; server error